# React reports syntax unexpected token？

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

**Error msg:**

```
Syntax error: D:/file/repo/webpage/react_demo/src/App.js: Unexpected token (34:5)

  32 |
  33 |   return (
> 34 |     <>
     |      ^
  35 |       <div className="status">{status}</div>
  36 |       <div className="board-row">
  37 |         <Square value={squares[0]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(0)} />
```

- I learnt from the react demo, but it didn't run on my local environment.

```
import React,{userState,Component} from "react";

function Square({ value, onSquareClick }) {
  return (
    <button className="square" onClick={onSquareClick}>
      {value}
    </button>
  );
}
```

**package json:**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "main": "/index.js",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "type": "module",
  
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-react"]
  
}
```

1. I have updated npm version
2. I have deleted npm modules and downloaded

Comment: I believe the file extension should be jsx

Comment: How do you build your project? Is this CRA? You can either change the file extension or configure the build system to use `*.js` for JSX files.

Comment: eh,you mean i change file extension is jsx?but i hava changed file extension app.jsx,it sill fail

Comment: Can you check with <React.Fragment></React.Fragment> in place of <> </>

Comment: yes, i use <React.Fragment></React.Fragment>,it success,

Comment: i use 'npm start' to compile it.

Comment: `npm start` is not a React specific build command. It's just a shorthand to call a specific script that is configured in your `package.json`.

Comment: can you try and upgrade react-scripts version "react-scripts": "5.0.1"?

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting error with Fragment shorthand <> </>, I recommend to use  `<React.Fragement> </React.Fragment>` which is equivalent to <></> as per [React Doc](https://react.dev/reference/react/Fragment)